# Missing Sites node in IIS7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I'm trying to publish a web application to the server of a client. when i connect to and go to IIS7. i find that the 'Sites' Node is missing there and only Start Page is shown.

Thank you for pointing some tracks for fixing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should connect to a server. Right click on Start Page and choose Connect to a Server, then type your Server name.

Comment: should i write down there the credentials i used for connecting to the server i'm trying to publish the weapp in ? because when i tried to do that, it says : Could not connect to the specified computer. Details: Unable to connect to the remport server. Thank you

Comment: look at this article http://marckean.wordpress.com/2012/07/08/remotely-managing-iis-on-windows-server-core-2008-r2/